# Confusing behavior when wiring together Rollup, ES modules, TypeScript, and JSX

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, rollupjs

The things I noted in the title - I started to learn them just recently. They are going not that smooth, so I have to ask this little question on StackOverflow.

### What I require

- Something to pack my stuff - here comes `Rollup`
- Bare module imports for my own module files - using `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve` for this
- Funny typed language - `TypeScript` and `@rollup/plugin-typescript`
- React with JSX - it is `react` and `react-dom` packages, and `typescript`, which is able to process JSX

I read these docs to wire these tools together:

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-typescript

I successfully used `Rollup`, `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve`, and `TypeScript`. But with addition of `React` things went odd.

### Demo project

Please look at the example project I made for illustration:
https://github.com/Ser5/RollupWireBug

```
git clone https://github.com/Ser5/RollupWireBug.git
cd RollupWireBug/
npm install or yarn install
npm run build
```

The project structure is:

```
/
    src/
        js/ - only folder that contains my code
            main.tsx - entry point
            test-class.js - for testing bare import
        buggy.tsx - should be excluded from building
    dist/
        bundle.js - Rollup output file
```

#### rollup.config.js

To my understanding the config should work like that:

```
resolve({
    moduleDirectories: ['node_modules/', 'src/js/'],
    extensions:        ['.js', '.ts', '.jsx', '.tsx'],
}),
```

^ This should mean to bare import modules from `node_modules/` and `src/js/`, searching for files with noted extensions.

And here comes the puzzling part:

```
typescript({
    include: [
        './**/*',
        //'src/js/**/*',
        //"node_modules/**/*",
    ],
    exclude: [
        "node_modules/",
        "dist/",
        "src/buggy.tsx",
    ],
}),
```

^ This is how a configuration works for me. I must write `./**/*` in the `include` - which seems odd for me, as I believe I don't need to include every file from the project root - I need only `src/js/`.

If instead of `./**/*` I use `src/js/**/*`, or `src/js/**/*` with `node_modules/**/*` - Rollup refuses to build the project, screeching:

```
src/js/main.tsx → dist/bundle.js...
[!] Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
src\js\main.tsx (7:13)
5:
6: let myName = 'Ser5';
7: let s      = <h1>{myName}</h1>;
                ^
8: console.log(s);
Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
```

It doesn't recognize the JSX syntax.

Because of `./**/*` in the `include` I also need to have the `exclude` section - otherwise Rollup/TypeScript will crawl into `src/buggy.js` and even `dist/`, and try to build them as well.

#### tsconfig.json

I understand it as follows:

```
"baseUrl": "./",
"paths": {
    "*": [
        "node_modules/*",
        "src/js/*",
    ],
},
```

^ "Go search modules in `node_modules/` and `src/js/` directories."

```
"outDir": "tsout",
```

^ Really no idea WTF is this. Looks like some temporary folder.

And if instead of this part in `rollup.config.js`

```
typescript({
    include: [
        './**/*',
    ],
    ...
}),
```

I write the same thing in `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    include: [
        './**/*',
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
```

The project still doesn't build - displaying `Error: Unexpected token` for JSX syntax.

### Questions

- Where am I wrong?
- Why for `@rollup/plugin-typescript` I have to include `./**/*` right from the root, and block some files with `include` section? Why can't I simply write `src/js/**/*` ?
- Why `include` works only for `@rollup/plugin-typescript`? And I can't write that `include` in `tsconfig.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will try to give you some hints:

- `outDir` option says where the JavaScript files will be generated
- `@rollup/plugin-typescript` will load any `compilerOptions` from the `tsconfig.json` file by default. So if you are passing any option to that (like you did in your repo) it will override those ones that you set in `tsconfig.json`. Might be better to decide where to config stuff for TS
- Specifically for your error. [See docs here](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/typescript#preserving-jsx-output).

You have to do this basically:

```
import jsx from 'acorn-jsx';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';

export default {
  // … other options …
  acornInjectPlugins: [jsx()],
  plugins: [typescript({ jsx: 'preserve' })]
};
```

Check [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) out by the way if you want to avoid all this config shenanigans! :)

Comment: "So if you are passing any option to that (like you did in your repo) it will disregard the tsconfig.json."  I'm pretty sure that is false.  It will try to make sense of the options that contradict (and throw the appropriate errors).  You're making it sound like *any* specified options fully negate your entire tsconfig.json, which is not true.

Comment: You are right. It was phrased in a misleading way. Passing options to the plugin directly overrides the tsconfig.ts not replace entirely. Will update the answer!